# Test Classes for Existing Salesforce Communities Controllers

Tags: apex, unit-test, community, controller, code-coverage

I would like to increase my unit test coverage.

I am using communities in our org.

Salesforce comes with a bunch of existing controllers for communities:

- ChangePasswordController
- SiteRegisterController
- SiteLoginController
- CommunitiesLandingController
- CommunitiesLoginController
- CommunitiesSelfRegConfirmController
- CommunitiesSelfRegController
- ForgotPasswordController
- LightningLoginFormController
- LightningSelfRegisterController
- MyProfilePageController
- LightningForgotPasswordController

Are there test classes available?

or

Does anyone have test classes they have already written?

Comment: If you are not using them delete them. Nothing worse when touching a code base than to find dead code that distracts from the real code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You dont need to write any code coverage for these. As soon as you enable communities salesforce creates these classes along with test classes.
If you enhance these classes then only you need to increase the code coverage.
[image]